# quarto yaml to render qmd files that start with _

Tags: rstudio, quarto

I'm playing around with two different models for my website in quarto, one includes all the chapters in the `index.qmd` file so I have to name each chapter with an underscore in front.

When I try to render the chapters separately, they aren't rendered as they start with _, e.g. "chapters/_02-Intro_to_analysis_software.qmd".

I've tried [explicitly telling quarto to render these chapters](https://quarto.org/docs/websites/) using `_quarto.yml`

```
project:
  type: website
  render: 
    - index.qmd
    - about.qmd
    - "chapters/_01-Intro_to_quant_methods.qmd"
    - chapters/_02-Intro_to_analysis_software.qmd
```

But when I run `quarto render` it only renders the about and index qmd files.

```
[...]
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code

?[31moutput file: index.knit.md

?[39m←[1m←[34m[2/2] about.qmd←[39m←[22m

Output created: _site\index.html
```

How do I get quarto to render files that start with an underscore?

Comment: As per [docs](https://quarto.org/docs/websites/#render-targets), it's not possible. Since **all valid Quarto input files (`.qmd`, `.ipynb`, `.md`, `.Rmd`) in the project directory will be rendered, except for ones with a file or directory prefix of _ (typically used for non-top-level files, e.g. ones included in other files)**

Comment: Fair enough. Might be a feature request in, it's hard to switch between different types of websites as is